# Conditionally include elements in swagger

Tags: swagger

I want to send following json request.

```
{
  "outboundMessageRequest": {
    "senderAddress": "{senderAddress}",
    "charging": {
      "description":"{description}",
      "amount" : "{amount}"
    },
    "outboundMessage": {
      "subject": "{subject}",
      "priority": "{priority}"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how do I remove charging element from request if user does not provide a value to description field?.

For example if user does not provide value for description elements, the server should receive following json.

```
{
  "outboundMessageRequest": {
    "senderAddress": "{senderAddress}",
    "outboundMessage": {
      "subject": "{subject}",
      "priority": "{priority}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swagger, you would describe this as two different schemas--one being the inbound schema, the other being the outbound.  You can even use `allOf` to compose the two schemas with relations between them.  For example:

```
    definitions:
      MessageRequest:
        properties:
          senderAddress:
            type: string
          outboundMessage:
            type: object
            properties:
              subject:
                type: string
              priority:
                type: string
      InboundMessage:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/MessageRequest'
          - properties:
              charging:
                type: object
                properties:
                  description:
                    type: string
                  amount:
                    type: number
                    format: double
```

This says that the inbound message is the same as the outbound message but with an additional complex property.